# Can I provide a parameter in my method only used by subclass?

Tags: java

If I have a method in class `A`:

```
protected String doSomething(Foo foo, Bar bar)
{
  foo.getString();
}
```

And I have another method in a subclass `B`:

```
@Override
protected String doSomething(Foo foo, Bar bar)
{
  if (bar.type == `something`)
  {
     return bar.getString();
  }
  return super.doSomething(foo, bar);
}
```

Basically class `A` shouldn't care about `Bar`, and it's only needed for class `B`.. is this a code smell? I wanted to override a particular method where a parameter is only used by the child class but it doesn't seem like the right approach.

Comment: In my opinion it's not good practice to have an unused parameter.

Comment: Instead of passing Bar as a parameter, consider having it as "a state" of the class (like a member variable). These kinds of questions can be better answered if you can provide the actual, concrete scenario and code.

Comment: In such case, those two should be different methods.

Answer (score 0):

As both classes have separate things to do with logic, but both classes are in Inheritance relation
Note: Make sure do you really need Inheritance relation between `A` and `B`

```
public class A{
//...
protected String doSomething(Foo foo)
{
  foo.getString();
}
//...
}

public class B extends A{
//...
//@Override // no need of overriding
protected String doSomething(Foo foo, Bar bar)
{
  if (bar.type == `something`)
  {
     return bar.getString();
  }
  return super.doSomething(foo, bar);
}
//...
}
```

Now time to call the methods...

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  A a1 = new A();//option1
  a.doSomething(new Foo());

  A a2 = new B();//option2, most suitable for you
  a2.doSomething(new Foo());
  a2.doSomething(new Foo(),new Bar());

  B b1 = new B();//option3
  b1.doSomething(new Foo(),new Bar());
}
```